# IMCE attempting to upload file greater than 10MB

Tags: files

Try to upload a PDF files around 30MB.
I can upload files < 10MB including PDF file no problem.

IMCE settings:
Profile User-1:
All settings are set to max eg.Maximum file size per upload set to 0
Permitted file extensions set to *
Maximum number of files per operation set to 0
Directories:

```
root/. (ie. the default . in textbox)
```

include subdirectories checked.

PHP info settings (confirmed with phpinfo())
post_max_size 300M 
upload_max_filesize 300M

Also tried
MaxRequestLen 300000000

What am I missing?

Mohan

Comment: where did you run your phpinfo(),    
try running it `example.com/admin/reports/status/php` and check if it is the same value.

Comment: Cross check, after changes to restart apache2 server. and check as @shrish said.

Comment: Yes I went to admin/reports/status/php and can confirm the values are as stated. Drupal installation on a shared hosted server.

Comment: Please describe the error you have ? Does it give you an error "You can't download a file of more than..." ? Does it time out ? Other ?